# Name i is not defined

Tags: python

Versions:
Python 3 
I have received name error : i is not defined when I was trying to use List Comprehension.
How could I solve this?

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [i*2 for a in a]
print(b)
```

Comment: you need to use this in your comprehension: `b = [i*2 for i in a]` .

Comment: You will need to look into python [Comprehensions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/comprehensions-in-python/)

Comment: you're trying to call `a` in your `a` list .and again you're trying multiple `i` value which is not callable in your list comprehensions.  your question answer:   `b = [i*2 for i in a]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as you are trying to list comprehension, you need to type i instead of a like that :  `b = [i*2 for i in a]`

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [i*2 for i in a]
print(b)
===========
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27990301)